# Using SLURM without a feature

Tags: benchmark, high-performance, slurm

Suppose my super computer has the following NODELIST's with the included features:

```
NODELIST      FEATURES
NodeA         (none)  
NodeB         specialfeature
```

and I am trying to benchmark performance using or not using the `specialfeature` feature. Measuring the performance of a run using `specialfeature` is easy. I simply call

```
sbatch --constraint="specialfeature" mybenchmarktest.exe
```

The above assures that my run happens on a node that contains the `specialfeature` feature (ie, node B). However, if I want to run the benchmark WITHOUT `specialfeature` I run in to a problem. Calling

```
sbatch mybenchmarktest.exe
```

means SLURM might run my task on NodeA or NodeB. Meaning my benchmarking might not be measuring what I want it to.

**Is there a way to ensure that a process runs without a feature?** I am imagining a call something like:

```
sbatch --contraint="!specialfeature" mybenchmarktest.exe
```

NOTE: In this trivial case, I know that I could just request it to run on NodeA (the node without the feature) but I'm looking for a more general way to tell SLURM "don't use such and such".

Comment: I'm still willing to hand out this bounty. Any one out there :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently (as of version 15.8) no way to negate a feature in such way. The only way is to define a complementary feature in the following way:

```
NODELIST      FEATURES
NodeA         nospecialfeature  
NodeB         specialfeature
```

and then submit a job with `--constraint=specialfeatures`,  and another one with `--constraint=nospecialfeature`.

If you cannot change the configuration, another option is to build manually the list of admissible hosts with a construct like the following:

```
sinfo -h --format "%N %f" | grep specialfeature  |\
   awk '{print $1}' | paste -d, -s | xargs scontrol show hostlist
```

and use the result with the `--nodelist` option. Feel free to combine `grep`'s to build your list.